# How to build boost with correct paths

Tags: c++, boost, build, filepath

I tried to build boost in a separate path on my Ubuntu 18 Linux system. I cloned the GIT repository since I want to have the latest version available (the package repositories provide an old version only). The library I want to use is `boost::timer`.

This is what I did:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 headers
./b2
```

This kind of worked. However I expected the static library to be located in a different path. It was compiled into this path:

> .../boost/bin.v2/libs/timer/build/gcc-9/release/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_timer.a

This path is very verbos and it contains the compiler and its version which means I would need to update the paths when updating GCC or changing the compiler.

I would have expected it here:

> .../boost/libs/timer/libboost_timer.a

Did I do something wrong? Is the placement expected that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when reading the build output carefully even a fool like me could notice that the actual path is `boost/stage/lib`. All built libs can be found there.